# List count specific element in apex

Tags: apex

Is there a way to count/size of the specific element in the List?, what I mean is 
count the each set by `Screen [700, 20]` & `prefix (us & ca)`

Here is the data looks like this:

```
(Screen [700,20]us, Screen [700,20]ca, Screen [300,60],ca, Screen [200,40]us)
```

Here is the code:

```
List<List<String>> screenTypeList = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> screenTypeAddList = new List<String>();
for(custom_obj__c c : /*SOQL*/) 
{ 
    typeList = new List<List<String>>
    {
        new List<String>{c.screen__c, c.prefix__c } 
        screenTypeAddList.add(screenTypeList[0][0] +screenTypeList[0][1] );
    }; 
}
```

the output should be like this based on the above data:

```
Screen [700, 20] - 2 counts // it has both prefix (us & ca)
Screen [300, 60] - 1 count
Screen [200, 40] - 1 count
```

Comment: Hi Nick, can you specify which pattern you are choosing first? the screen array one or us and ca one? based on that i might have something for you

Comment: I'm not using any pattern and I'm pretty much open to use any pattern as long as it works :)

Comment: If I don´t misunderstand, you can build a map where the key is screen__c and stores the count for each screen__c: Map<String, Integer>. If you are interested whit this solution, I can post an answer with further details.

Comment: Sure post your solution @D.Cruz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `c.screen__c` is a string like `"Screen [700, 20]"`, correct me if that is not correct, the solution will be to use a map to store the count for each screen__c.

```
Map<String, Integer> countByScreen = new Map<String, Integer>();

for(custom_obj__c c : /*SOQL*/) 
{
    Integer count = 1;

    if(countByScreen.containsKey(c.screen__c)){
        count = countByScreen.get(c.screen__c) + 1;
    }

    countByScreen.push(c.screen__c, count);
}
```

Then you can iterate over the map to test the result:

```
for (String screen : countByScreen.keySet()){
    Integer count = countByScreen.get(screen);
    System.debug(screen + ' = ' + count);
}
```